# Excel VBA, "object doesn't support this property or method", Error 438

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to excel VBA and i'm making a program for school, but I keep stumbling on error 438 in this code. Can anyone help me out?
I called the function at the end of my code. I'm making a table appear on a new sheet. And the values that will go in the table are calculated from other values from different sheets.

```
Function TonnageBepalen(kraancapaciteit As Double, transporttijd As Double, ton As Double, aantal As Integer) Dim waarde As Double

waarde = Application.WorksheetFunction.Afronden(8 * 60 / transporttijd, 0) * aantal * ton

TonnageBepalen = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(kraancapaciteit, waarde)

End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim kraan As String
    Dim tonkraan As Double
    Dim laadtijd As Double
    Dim transport As String
    Dim tontransport As Double
    Dim kmu As Double
    Dim lostijd As Double
    Dim kraancap As Double
    Dim afstand As Double
    Dim tijd As Double
    Dim tonnage As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim gemsnel As Double
    Dim transporttijd As Double
    Dim rij As Integer
    Dim cell As String

    Bladtoevoegen ("transport")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Tabellen transport"
    rij = 1
    cell = "A" + CStr(rij)
    Worksheets("Adres").Activate
    afstand = Cells(2, 5).Value
    tijd = Cells(2, 6).Value
    gemsnel = afstand / (tijd / 60)

    Worksheets("transport").Activate
    For i = 3 To Cells(1, 8).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        transport = Cells(i, 8).Value
        tontransport = Cells(i, 9).Value
        kmu = Cells(i, 10).Value
        lostijd = Cells(i, 11).Value
        MaakTabelTonnage
        Range(cell).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        rij = rij + 6

        Worksheets("kranen").Activate
        For j = 3 To Cells(1, 7).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
            kraan = Cells(j, 7).Value
            tonkraan = Cells(j, 8).Value
            laadtijd = Cells(j, 10).Value
            kraancap = tonkraan * 8

            Worksheets("Tabellen transport").Activate
            transporttijd = Transporttijdbepalen(afstand, kmu, gemsnel, lostijd, laadtijd)
            For k = 1 To 15
                tonnage = TonnageBepalen(kraancap, transporttijd, tontransport, k)
                Cells(rij, k + 3) = tonnage
                Next k
            rij = rij + 1
            Next j
        rij = rij + 2
        Next i
End Sub
```

I expect the output to be a double number.

Comment: Your Function works fine for me. What is your input, and how are you calling this function?

Comment: You need to declare the output type in the Function header, you are missing As Double on the end. Function FnName (afstand As Double) As Double

Comment: If that’s no enough I would break down the function into smaller pieces and build it up. Maybe even over a number of lines... when you step through it (using F8) you should find where the issue is occurring.

Comment: @Josh That doesn't work. When I run my program, everything gets a value, except Transporttijdbepalen. There it says: Transporttijdbepalen = empty

Comment: @AxelSix it's vital you include the code that uses this Function. Your Function seems fine, so the problem must be due to how you're calling it

Comment: I'm so sorry i showed the wrong function, it's this function who doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `WorksheetFunction` together with a local formula name. `WorksheetFunction` instead uses formulae native to Excel, aka English. I happen to know "Afronden" means "Round".

The function output should also be specified as mentioned by Josh:

```
Option Explicit

Function TonnageBepalen(kraancapaciteit As Double, transporttijd As Double, ton As Double, aantal As Integer) As Double

    Dim waarde As Double

    waarde = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(8 * 60 / transporttijd, 0) * aantal * ton

    TonnageBepalen = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(kraancapaciteit, waarde)

End Function
```